# git - cannot push to repository - bug with hashmap

Tags: git

When I try to push to repository, I got this message

```
BUG: remote.c:236: hashmap_put overwrote entry after hashmap_get returned NULL
```

Any idea what is wrong? Google shows nothing...

When I try push to another repository on the same server, it is working correctly. The problem is only with one repo.

Local Git version: 2.36.0.windows.1

Server Git version: 2.19.2

Comment: Which version of Git are you running on the server (and locally)? Did you already run `git fsck` in this repo?

Comment: for reference, seen on github: [remote.c:236 @ master](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1553f5e/remote.c#L236) (commit `1553f5e` is the current state of `master`)

Comment: @knittl Git version added to question. However, a different repo on the same server, accesed from the same local git is working fine. `git fsck` should run on local or server?

Comment: @MartinPerry run `git fsck` on the server in the broken repo and locally (but I assume the server repo is corrupt)

Comment: @knittl `fsck` run on both machines, but problem is still there

Comment: @MartinPerry, did `fsck` report anything suspicious or are both repos "ok"?

Comment: @knittl It reported nothing, only done after analysis: `Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (23956/23956), done.
Checking connectivity: 18782, done.`

Answer (score 5):

Based on reporting problem to git team, the problem was caused by branch with an empty name `""`. After removing this form `.git/config`, pushing works again.
However, the problem is passed to git team and will probably be solved in future version.

Answer (score 4):

Git has self-detected an internal error.  Report this to the Git mailing list (`git@vger.kernel.org`).  The output from `git config --list --show-origin` may also be useful to the Git maintainers, along with the output of `git ls-remote` on the remote in question (`origin`, probably).  (The bug itself is in your Windows Git; the server version of Git *should* be irrelevant, but it won't hurt to mention that too.)